# Error during the creating of custom processors apache nifi

Tags: java, maven, groovy, apache-nifi, maven-plugin

I tried to build my package with NiFi custom-processor using `mvn clean package` command and I got the following output:

```
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time:  3.794 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2021-05-17T14:33:42+02:00
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.8.1:testCompile 
(groovy-tests) on project mycustom-processor: Execution groovy-tests of goal
 org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.8.1:testCompile failed: 
Plugin org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.8.1 or one of its dependencies
 could not be resolved: Failed to collect dependencies at 
org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:jar:3.8.1 
-> org.codehaus.groovy:groovy-eclipse-batch:jar:2.5.4-01: Failed to read artifact descriptor for 
org.codehaus.groovy:groovy-eclipse-batch:jar:2.5.4-01: Could not transfer artifact
 org.codehaus.groovy:groovy-eclipse-batch:pom:2.5.4-01 from/to bintray 
(https://dl.bintray.com/groovy/maven): 
Access denied to: https://dl.bintray.com/groovy/maven/org/codehaus/groovy/groovy-eclipse-batch/2.5.4-01/groovy-eclipse-batch-2.5.4-01.pom, 
ReasonPhrase: Forbidden. -> [Help 1]
[ERROR]
```

Does anybody know how to handle this issue related to the *maven-compiler-plugin:3.8.1:testCompile*,  please ?
I use Apache NiFi version 1.13.2 and `mvn install -DskipTests` does not change anything.

Comment: maybe the reason that bintray is going to be closed... https://jfrog.com/blog/into-the-sunset-bintray-jcenter-gocenter-and-chartcenter/

Comment: This the way to build custom nifi processors ,[Build a Custom NiFi processor](https://community.cloudera.com/t5/Community-Articles/Build-Custom-Nifi-Processor/ta-p/244734)

Answer (score 9):

The reason for this error is that the pom's url is not accessable.

Currently, groovy-eclipse-batch-2.5.4-01.pom link is forbidden.(dl.bintray.com/groovy/maven/org/codehaus/groovy/groovy-eclipse-batch/2.5.4-01/groovy-eclipse-batch-2.5.4-01.pom)

Check if groovy-eclipse-batch exists in your maven repository.
Or just find a valid version on mvnrepository.com and use it. (https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.codehaus.groovy/groovy-eclipse-batch)

For example, change version of groovy-eclipse-batch to 2.5.6-01.

Try adding the following to your parent pom for the bundle project :

```
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.8.1</version>            
            <configuration>
                <source>1.8</source>
                <target>1.8</target>
                <encoding>UTF-8</encoding>
            </configuration>                        
            <dependencies>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.codehaus.groovy</groupId>
                    <artifactId>groovy-eclipse-batch</artifactId>
                    <version>2.5.6-01</version>
                </dependency>
            </dependencies>                 
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Before add the dependency :

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.8.1:testCompile (groovy-tests) on project mytest: Execution groovy-tests of goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.8.1:testCompile failed: Plugin org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.8.1 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: Failed to collect dependencies at org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:jar:3.8.1 -> org.codehaus.groovy:groovy-eclipse-batch:jar:2.5.4-01: Failed to read artifact descriptor for org.codehaus.groovy:groovy-eclipse-batch:jar:2.5.4-01: Could not transfer artifact org.codehaus.groovy:groovy-eclipse-batch:pom:2.5.4-01 from/to bintray (https://dl.bintray.com/groovy/maven): Access denied to: https://dl.bintray.com/groovy/maven/org/codehaus/groovy/groovy-eclipse-batch/2.5.4-01/groovy-eclipse-batch-2.5.4-01.pom -> [Help 1]
```

After add the dependency :

```
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Reactor Summary for mytest 1.0.0-SNAPSHOT:
[INFO]
[INFO] mytest ............................................. SUCCESS [  3.611 s]
[INFO] nifi-mytestnar-processors .......................... SUCCESS [ 11.278 s]
[INFO] nifi-mytestnar-nar ................................. SUCCESS [  0.983 s]
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time:  19.448 s
```

Comment: Thanks. This helped a lot. Just to add a little for those of us not super familiar with Maven. You can change the source/target of the plugin if you are not using Java 8. And the groovy-eclipse-batch dependency version can also correspond to the available options if you want to use a newer version: https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.codehaus.groovy/groovy-eclipse-batch I think anyway. Not a Maven expert, but it worked for me. :D

Comment: I am very angry with jFrog / Artifactory for making me do extra work. This is the 3rd time this has come up. Migrating to Nexus. They really couldn't have just setup a mirror?

Answer (score 5):

Add the below property to your pom.xml

```
    <nifi.groovy.version>2.5.6</nifi.groovy.version>
```

Comment: you made my day

Comment: This one works great. Baiscally issue is 'org.codehaus.groovy:groovy-eclipse-batch:pom:2.5.4-01' is no longer available on mvncentral and above property changes required version to 2.5.6 which is available. Checkout https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.codehaus.groovy/groovy-eclipse-batch