# Error when trying to build nifi-maven project

Tags: java, maven, apache-nifi

Running on a mac, I'm trying to add a simple nar to a nifi install.
Following instructions found on [here](https://itnext.io/deep-dive-into-a-custom-apache-nifi-processor-c2191e4f89a0), I use mvn generate to start the nifi processor project. I then immediately run mvn clean install, without making any changes, to create the nar package but I keep running into this error

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.8.1:testCompile (groovy-tests) on project test.test: Execution groovy-tests of goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.8.1:testCompile failed: Plugin org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.8.1 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: Failed to collect dependencies at org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:jar:3.8.1 -> org.codehaus.groovy:groovy-eclipse-batch:jar:2.5.4-01: Failed to read artifact descriptor for org.codehaus.groovy:groovy-eclipse-batch:jar:2.5.4-01: Could not transfer artifact org.codehaus.groovy:groovy-eclipse-batch:pom:2.5.4-01 from/to bintray (https://dl.bintray.com/groovy/maven): authorization failed for https://dl.bintray.com/groovy/maven/org/codehaus/groovy/groovy-eclipse-batch/2.5.4-01/groovy-eclipse-batch-2.5.4-01.pom, status: 403 Forbidden -> [Help 1]
```

Comment: Answer here : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67570165/error-during-the-creating-of-custom-processors-apache-nifi

Answer (score 0):

Try with upgrading groovy version to 2.5.6 as below
<nifi.groovy.version>2.5.6</nifi.groovy.version> in pom.xml